# How can I break out of a shell script loop if the input is being handled by an inner "while read"?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is a shell script. Please extrapolate the controlled-environment random number generation subshell to the use of this in an asynchronous logging situation (I intend to use it for inotifywait output).

```
group=0
(
  for val in {1..10}; do 
    echo "$RANDOM/20000" | bc | xargs sleep # this waits 0, 1, or 2 seconds before each number is printed
    echo $val 
  done 
) | while true; do 
      while read -t 1 line; do 
        echo "read time=$group read=$line" 
      done
      ((group++))
    done
```

This produces output like this:

```
read time=1 read=1
read time=2 read=2
read time=2 read=3
read time=3 read=4
read time=3 read=5
read time=3 read=6
read time=4 read=7
read time=5 read=8
read time=5 read=9
read time=5 read=10
```

But it then hangs and does not exit. It is stuck in the outer loop, continually incrementing `group`:

```
$ echo $group 
1336794
```

Clearly the inner loop has exited due to input having finished, and the incrementation of the variable went into hyperdrive.

How to exit the loop? Is there like a `else` clause of some sort that I can hack on to the inner for loop in order to `break` out of the outer loop, once the input has finished coming in?

Surely there must be a more robust method than doing timing in the outer loop to see if it went through too fast.

Comment: did you try `break n` .... n you can specify the nesting/number of loops you wanna get out of .... (if check for the break 2 stmt.)

Comment: Notice how i never wrote a `break`. Where would it go? The inner loop times itself out every second.

Comment: its a intresting question , +1 for that.

Comment: A controversial question, it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo outputs
for val in {1..10}; do
    echo "$RANDOM/20000" | bc | xargs sleep
    echo $val 
done > outputs &
group=0
time=$(date +%s%N)
while read line; do
    ctime=$(date +%s%N)
    [ $(( $ctime - $time )) -gt 1000000000 ] && let group++
    echo "read time=$group read=$line"
    time=$ctime
done < outputs
```

Comment: Where do i put it? The only thing I can think of is make the inner loop also infinite loop, and then manually break out of both loops when I notice the right condition from `read`.

Comment: Okay, that's reasonable to solve this meaningless example question, but in real life I don't know my log's gonna end right **there**, now am I?

Comment: according to manpage, `read -t` returns false when it times out. Doesn't it also return false when the input ends? Therefore i wouldnt be able to tell when input ends. As to the second point, I concede that, will edit

Comment: where does the input come from?

Comment: `inotifywait -m`. Trying to "collect" output so it wont run a script 50 times if I change 50 files simultaneously

Comment: and what is your termination condition? also, why do you need the sub-shell and the outer loop?

Comment: Well. there is no termination condition *per se*. The whole shebang gets `kill`ed usually. I guess if the program (`inotifywait` in this case) died I wanted to be able to cleanly detect that occurrence which is what I do now. If you have any better ideas of how to "collect" multiple lines of quickly arriving input separately from any lines coming after a certain timeout period, i'd love to hear it. Perl, Python, what have you.

Comment: That does work. It is based on timing though, and i mentioned in my question that its not the ideal solution. I wonder if the fifo is necessary?

Comment: I don't think fifo is necessary, but your OP is also based on timing, I mean that is how you group the input AFAIU.

Comment: Well. Yeah. But that only shoots down my point half-way... It's just not clean at all to use **two** independent timers to do something that clearly only has one time-dependent component. Do you get what I'm saying? I'm starting to see maybe the way to do it is something that uses a single timer but touches the filesystem a lot in order to synchronize. Which is also pretty awful....

Comment: there is only one timer here, note that I removed the delay from your read

Comment: Ah. Hmm. I see it now. I think that means it's bedtime. This is pretty solid. Good job. Have an accept. If you don't mind/are interested/feeling generous, could you get it to use a pipe and no fifo? Isn't it just moving the var initializations out front and piping the two while loops? Which would mean that the second while loop is a self contained solution for my use case.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized this is an insufficient solution as it subtly changes the behavior. The reason I had the outer loop before was that it would be capable of knowing when the timeout occurs, rather than after the next input after the timeout trips and it finds out after-the-fact that the last line came in however much time past the timeout period. This is significant because the latter makes less sense in the use case. I think a good solution is to adapt this sort of logic but get it done properly with Perl or Python

Comment: I guess it comes down to requiring asynchronous IO.

Comment: Well... I'll re-accept it, because for the express purpose I'm using this code for, that subtle difference is actually not a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on read return code. According to bash documentation when `read -t` exit for timeout it has a return code greater than 128, so you can distinguish EOF from timeout.

```
function random_timed_output
{
  for val in {1..10}; do
    sleep $(( $RANDOM/20000 ))
    echo $val 
  done
}

group=0
random_timed_output | while true; do
  read -t 1 line
  rc=$?
  if [ $rc -gt 128 ]; then
    #read exit for timeout
    ((group++))
  elif [ $rc -gt 0 ]; then
    #read exit for error or EOF
    break
  else
    #read exit OK
    echo "read time=$group read=$line" 
  fi
done
```

Comment: Not on CentOS. Returns 1 both cases. Where'd you test this?

Comment: @StevenLu: Ubuntu 13.04, bash 4.2, see also documentation for `read' builtin here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: Well then. `% bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` I think working around it with a manual timer makes for more portability. But definitely +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test $ cat zcntr.sh
 ilimit=10; ## the length of list in for loop ... 

grp=0
(   for val in {1..10}; do
     #echo "$RANDOM/10000" | bc | xargs sleep
     sleep $(($RANDOM/10000));
     echo $val
     done
 ) | while true; do

  while read -t 1 line; do
    echo "read time=$grp read=$line"
  done

  ((grp++));

  if [ $grp -eq $ilimit ]
     then
       break ;
  fi

done
```

output is not satisfactory , but i will have a look at it later :

```
Kaizen ~/so_test $ ./zcntr.sh
  read time=0 read=1
  read time=0 read=2
  read time=1 read=
  read time=1 read=4
  read time=1 read=5
  ./zcntr.sh: line 13: read: read error: 0: Permission denied
  read time=4 read=7
  read time=6 read=
  read time=7 read=
  read time=7 read=10
```

does this help anyhow ?

Comment: @Steven Lu , okay ..... srry i didnt look at that , was trying to figure out why the read's failing ??

Comment: Maybe your `$(($RANDOM/10000))` isn't as good as my original and writes zero bytes sometimes or does something else that is weird?

Comment: now i got even more confused ..... @ Steve could you provide a bit more info on what you are trying to do ?  ... edit the question itself with the actual scenario if thats ok with you ?

Comment: yeah that is the case ..... i tested it seperately , it does give 0 sometimes ... but thats for sleep the var is set by the for counter which is echoed to the read in while via pipe..... whys that unassigned :(

Comment: I dunno. Read the other stuff here to see my motivations for this question. I believe @perreal solved it pretty nicely, I may post back with a non-fifo pipe only solution later if I can figure one out.